# MySQL JOIN and LIMIT TO 1

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Almost perfect code... but It's getting duplicates from actions_logs table because every user have multiple login entries for history purpose.

I've tested a lot of options but ther's no working example on the web.

[image: sequelpro with current result]

```
select `users`.* from `users` left join `action_logs` on `action_logs`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` and `action_logs`.`type` = 'login' order by `action_logs`.`created_at` desc, `id` desc
```

Expected result will be full user list sorted by loggedin date.

That sql is a result of Laravel code:

[image: laravel code]

```
if($value == 'last_login') {
            return $this->builder->select('users.*')
                                 ->leftJoin('action_logs', function ($join) {
                                     $join->on('action_logs.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                                          ->where('action_logs.type', '=', 'login');
                                     })->orderBy('action_logs.created_at', $this->request->get('sort'))
                                       ->orderBy('id', $this->request->get('sort'));
        }
```

Comment: [starting point](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#104), or lookup groupwise-max and there are more complete answers.

Comment: [versioned tables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/system-versioned-tables/) might be a newer way of keeping a historical record of the same table with queries that make lookup easier.

Comment: Only SELECT precisely what you need.  Avoid using `*` as a matter of best practice.  You won't need to access the users' hashed passwords, so don't query for them

Answer (score 0):

You should used DISTINCT Query but in order for you to remove duplicate results you should remove the "created_at" in the select since every logged in is created at different time.